# Combine multiple similar JavaScript functions into one

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating an extension that requires copying to clipboard, but I don't want to have 18 different functions that do (pretty much) the exact same thing.

This is the function that I wrote:

```
function copyS1_1() {
    var letter_to_copy = document.getElementById('textarea-S1-1');
    letter_to_copy.select();
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(letter_to_copy.value);
}
function copyS1_2() {
    var letter_to_copy = document.getElementById('textarea-S1-2');
    letter_to_copy.select();
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(letter_to_copy.value);
}
```

Each function is called 'copyS#_#' for 'Section' then the number in that section. I don't want to have 18 of these, so I'm looking for a way to simplify it down to 3 functions (one for each Section, there's 3.)

Comment: Use function arguments. Declare the element id (or the two #s) as a parameter.

Comment: "*simplify it down to 3 functions*" - why not go the full way down to just 1 function?

Comment: @Bergi I could, and it would be better, but I didn't know how to go about doing it to begin with, so I just said something that seemed like it might be easier, and in what Cam said, I would be using 3 functions, but seeing how Cam did it, I can simplify it down to 1 function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a parameter:

```
function copyS1(id) {
    var letter_to_copy = document.getElementById('textarea-S1-' + id);
    letter_to_copy.select();
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(letter_to_copy.value);
}
```

Use like this:

```
copyS1(1)
copyS1(2)
...
```

Comment: so I actually tried this, but I think because I'm using `document.getElementById('Sec1_BTN1').addEventListener('click', copyS1(1));` with your suggestion, it's triggering the event on page load. Any ideas?

Comment: @jasonhe Yes! As you know, the second parameter to `addEventListener` is the function you want JS to run when the event happens.

The problem with your code: JS thinks the function you want it to run is `undefined`, because `copyS1(1)`, which is run as soon as you call addEventListener, evaluates to `undefined`.

What you actually want is this:

`document.getElementById('Sec1_BTN1').addEventListener('click', function() { copyS1(1) });`

That works because `function() { copyS1(1) }` evaluates to a function

Comment: Another way to do this would be with "bind" — see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind for background. But the code would look like this: `document.getElementById('Sec1_BTN1').addEventListener('click', copyS1.bind(null, 1));`. It works because `copyS1.bind(null, 1)` evaluates as "a function which calls `copyS1(1)`".

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with template literals and function arguments.

```js
function copyFuncForAny(num1, num2) {
    var letter_to_copy = document.getElementById(`textarea-S${num1}-${num2}`);
    letter_to_copy.select();
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(letter_to_copy.value);
}

copyFuncForAny(1, 1);
copyFuncForAny(1, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

its simple just your own function like this

```
function copyText(id) {
    var letter_to_copy = document.getElementById(id);
    letter_to_copy.select();
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(letter_to_copy.value);
}
```

use it as many time as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply pass the string as an argument?

```js
function copyS1_1(id) {
  var letter_to_copy = document.getElementById(id);
  letter_to_copy.select();
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(letter_to_copy.value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**textarea-S1-1** its only changing value here, so you can pass it as  paramater to a general function

```
function copyS1(textarea) {
    var letter_to_copy = document.getElementById(textarea);
    letter_to_copy.select();
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(letter_to_copy.value);
}
```

and use it as follow

```
var copyS1_1 = copyS1('textarea-S1-1')
var copyS1_2 = copyS1('textarea-S1-2')
```